# Doesn't Protocol Oriented programming bring the same old issue of code duplication which inheritance primarily solved?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, protocols

**Overview**

I was trying to get my head around Swift's Protocol Oriented Programming paradigm. As per Apple's WWDC 2015 video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/ Protocols can achieve everything that inheritance can and also solves the fundamental issue with inheritance.

Though Protocols solves the problem of multiple inheritance by capturing each capability (functionality) as protocol and allowing a class/struct to confirm multiple protocols, I believe Protocols can never replace inheritance for the following reason.

Lets assume I am implementing College/School automation software and there are two Entities, Staff and Principal and lets assume they both take class but principal along with taking class controls the staff.

So I create a protocol which will model the common capability which is taking class. So let's create a protocol.

```
protocol staffProtocol {
    var classHour : Int { get set}
    var numberOfClass : Int? { get set }

    mutating func doesWork()
}

extension staffProtocol {
    mutating func doesWork(){
        classHour = 9
        numberOfClass = 4
        print("Takes calss")
    }
}
```

As Taking class is a common task for both staff and principal so I provided a default extension which provides a implementation for `doesWork()` and says takes class.

Now let's write a Staff struct which will confirm to staffProtocol,

```
struct Staff : staffProtocol {
        var classHour: Int = 0
        var numberOfClass: Int? = 0
    }
```

Now if I create a staff object as

```
var staff = Staff()
staff.doesWork()
```

Everything works absolutely fine, now lets create a Principal struct which will also extend staffProtocol,

```
struct Principal : staffProtocol {
    var classHour: Int = 0
    var numberOfClass: Int? = 0

    mutating func doesWork() {
           print("Also controls other staff")
    }
}
```

Now along with teaching he also controls other staff, so if I override `doesWork()` and write `"Also controls other staff"`. Now the code in default extension will never be called.

Now in order to provide both teaching capability and controlling capability, I have two methods,

1. I can create another protocol which will model controlling capability and make principal struct to extend it
2. Copy the whole code in default extension of  `staffProtocol` to the principal struct's doesWork implementation and add a line which says Also controls other staff.

**Issues:**

*Issue with Solution 1*. We faced the similar issue in Inheritance, when there was need to implement the capabilities which belonged to two different parent classes and as multiple inheritance was not allowed we used to create the capability as a component and add the component as a property to parent class so that we can achieve multiple capability without having to implement multiple inheritance (which is anyway not allowed). But apple says its too much of code and absolutely not essential.

Even with protocol oriented programming if I have to implement each capability as a protocol isn't am running into same nook of the problem? Rather than creating a capability as a component am I not creating it as a protocol? How is that protocol adding benefit here?

*Issues with solution 2*. Because I can't call the default extension of the protocol and end up writing the whole code in struct specific implementation again, Haven't I ended up in code duplication issue which is the common problem which inheritance tried solving in a very first place?

**Question**

Question am trying to find solution is not how can I solve it? There are 100 ways to solve each problem, all I am trying to ask is,

1. Is protocol programming really an alternative to Object oriented programming?
2. Is protocol really a replacement to inheritance ? If yes at what cost? Writing simply super.doesWork() was clear or writing a separate protocol for each capability?

I might have completely misunderstood the concept of Protocol Oriented Programming, please help me understand the same.

Comment: Just a comment, _"Takes class" & "Also controls other staff" are never nearly related_. So you end up writing ___separate___ behavior for each of them. It doesn't make sense to _unify_ them together. For a further detailed explanation and answers for your trailing question see my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

(Very late to the party though. I came across this thread after having some beginning level knowledge about the **`POP`**)

Suppose, you are going to write some bird classes. Like:

- **Flappy Bird**
- **Swift Bird**
- **Stork Bird**
- **Penguin Bird**
- **Ostrich Bird**
- **Eagle Bird**

Some of them ***can fly*** and some ***can't***. In OOP, you have various options to design. Most commons are:

1. You design a base class **Fly**, then by subclassing it you design **Bird** and then you use this **Bird** as the base class for all the bird classes in the question. Override the *flying/not flying* behavior for each bird type.
2. Or, you can have a base class **Fly**, you subclass it for **FlyingBird**. And then you have another base class **NotFlyingBird**. After that you subclass these two classes according to your need.

The above approaches work. But you see for the ***case 1:***

> Every time you create a new bird, you are also inheriting some capabilities that you don't need maybe.

And in the ***case 2:***

> You create two separate base class of your need! What if you need to write something common for **FlyingBird** and **NotFlyingBird**? You will probably end up changing your mind to use the *approach 1* here.

And lastly, every time you change your mind in later time you end up inheriting from different base class. Or just adding all of the behaviors in a *god-like* class

---

Now see, how you can design this with **`POP`** approach.

```
protocol Flyable { ... }
protocol Bird { ... }

struct Flappy: Bird, Flyable { ... } //it's a bird & can fly
struct SwiftBird: Bird, Flyable { ... } //it's a bird & can fly
struct Stork: Bird, Flyable { ... } //it's a bird & can fly
struct Penguin: Bird { ... } //it's a bird but can't fly
struct Ostrich: Bird { ... } //it's a bird but can't fly
struct Eagle: Bird, Flyable { ... } //it's a bird & can fly
```

See! how `POP` really shine? ***So, it’s a good thing you didn’t take the inheritance approach, and make all birds flyable after all!***

With protocol oriented programming you just don't magically inherit everything from the **Super class**. You are enforcing to provide their own. With this approach, you are ***adding behaviors***. So you can keep out the burden off your shoulder.

> If you need anything *very new*, you just add to them and *not enforcing every other one to have that very new thing without their actual consent*.

This [Introducing Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift 3](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148448/introducing-protocol-oriented-programming) article from RayWenderlich may even lighten up you a bit more.

You might even have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146631/3687801) from a different thread.

---

Let's answer your trailing questions in short:

1. Is protocol programming really an alternative to OOP? `->` **Not always. But it has it's shine.**
2. Is protocol really a replacement to inheritance? `->` **Again, No. But!! If you are designing from the scratch it's worth it to give this idea a shot.**

Comment: Appreciate your effort to explain the POP and advantages of POP over OOP in some specific cases :) Hence +1 But the question continue to persist :) Question stem from the statement that apple in its introductory speech to POP said anything that you can do with inheritance can also be achieved with POP. This is in reference to Rusty programmer if you remember the video. True that each capability can be sculpted as protocol and you can provide default implementation to them but none of those in anyway supports code reusability. So though I agree that POP has it advantage over OOP

Comment: in some cases Apple's statement of POP is an alternate to OOP is wrong and with POP though you get yourself out of the hideous pit of inheritance but you will end up duplication of code :) Take a look at my article https://learnwithmehere.blogspot.in/2017/02/is-protocol-oriented-programming-game.html You concluded the same thing I concluded in my article :) Hence Ill keep the discussion open ended by not accepting your answer yet :) But I have upvoted your answer already

Comment: Yup. I'm just gathering enough knowledge on this topic whenever I get my time. Actually I'm not that good in writing, so it's just a wrap-up of my thoughts. So, I'm not expecting of _acceptance_ of the answer yet 

Comment: Oh well. Great. I just finished reading your article. It's very well executed, sorry explained . May I have a suggestion for you? ___That post deserves a place in a popular blogpost like___ **[Medium](https://medium.com)**. More people should know your thoughts on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the appreciative words :D Am glad u think it deserves to be in Medium Ill create an account and post the articles soon :) Thanks for the suggestion