# Adding to a default implementation of a protocol inside a view controller (like calling "Super" on a protocol)

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

What we have here is a protocol with some default values inside a protocol extension:

```
extension CellsProtocol {

    func registerCells(tableView:UITableView, viewController: AnyClass){
        let bundle : Bundle = Bundle(for: viewController.self)
        tableView.registerCell(a: HeaderImageTableViewCell(), bundle: bundle)
    }
}
```

Basically we want to keep the default protocol function where it registers a cell but want to add more cells to be registered in the VC where the protocol is being used, something similar to calling "super" like this:

```
class cellsVC: UIViewController, CellsProtocol {

    func registerCells(tableView:UITableView, viewController: AnyClass){
    super.registerCells// This doesn't work but would like something with similar ability
 tableView.registerCell(a: BodyTableViewCell(), bundle: bundle)
    }
}
```

Comment: You cant achieve it with Swift protocols you will rather have to create a base class and override its method in cellsVC. Swift Protocols default implementations are intended for as is use. Any class interested in providing customized implementation should consider writing from scratch cant use parent (default implementation) code

Comment: It is the issue with POP (Protocol Oriented Programming) Though it overcomes the draw back of OOP (Object Oriented Programming) we have to agree that it takes away few of the benefits we enjoyed with inheritance. Combination of COP(Component Oriented Programming) and POP might help but again cumbersome approach Here are my thoughts on the same : https://learnwithmehere.blogspot.in/2017/02/is-protocol-oriented-programming-game.html

Comment: Finally here is my question on the similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409877/doesnt-protocol-oriented-programming-bring-the-same-old-issue-of-code-duplicati unanswered though